# Azure Release Pipeline for Flask and React

Tags: reactjs, azure, flask, azure-pipelines

As a newbie to azure cloud platform I'm having trouble understanding the correct way to build a release pipeline for an app based on React + Flask + ArangoDB.

I have managed to put a build pipeline for React and Flask apps but having trouble creating a release pipeline for it using *Azure Linux App Service*.

What is the standard practice to deploy such a tech stack (In my case React + Flask + ArnagoDB)?

---

Below is to provide a complete picture for someone else going through the same process. Below screenshots are from app services, configured to deploy React and  Flask apps. Specific details for Flask app service configuration provided in  @a2441918 answer.

[image: A single deployment job with 2 tasks]

[image: React deploymnet app service]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have for a Flask app.

You need to create new app services for the entire stack.

Startup command: gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 startup:app

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I add another _app service deploy_ to pipeline it replaces the react deployment.

Comment: i have multiple. you should create new app services. you cannot deploy both together.

Comment: I ended up creating another app service to it. I guess I have to create another one to deploy my db.

Comment: You are.. create new app services for every service like UI/api/db

Comment: Stackoverflow required me to update the question. Could you please update your answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: Updated the answer